# HttpContext.Current.User returning system.security.claims.windowsprincipal instead of system.security.claims.ClaimPrincipal

Tags: c#, office365, owin

I have two websites and both have authentication from office365.

From one website its working fine.

but on other website HttpContext.Current.User returning system.security.claims.windowsprincipal instead of   system.security.claims.ClaimPrincipal

But when i checked on chrome version <50 its working fine for this website also.

Please help

Comment: "But when i checked on chrome..." - as opposed to *what* from before? You've given us *half* of the information there.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever   when i browse our web application on my machine with  Windows 10 & latest chrome version its not working .But when i browse the same application on windows XP machine with chrome version 49 its working fine.